# RN 0.69 >= Command 'npx react-native-asset' is not working

Tags: react-native, fonts, assets, autolink

I have everything set up properly, my fonts that I am trying to link are in `/assets/fonts/` and my `react-native-config.js` file is in the root directory. It looks like this...

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios:{},
        android:{}
    },
    assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

I've also tried it looking like this...

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts']
}
```

I've followed the directions [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-custom-fonts-react-native/) and [here](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/use-custom-fonts-in-react-native) as well as a gazillion other sites I closed out of. What the hell am I doing wrong-- I've done this before and never gotten this error, which looks like this...

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/nicklanese/Documents/GitHub/TomAppDirectory/TomApp_iOS/react-native.config.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/nicklanese/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/react-native-asset/lib/cli.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ls /Users/nicklanese/Documents/GitHub/TomAppDirectory/TomApp_iOS/react-native.config.js
```

> I have everything set up properly, my fonts that I am trying to link are in /assets/fonts/ and my react-native-config.js file is in the root directory. It looks like this...

Looks like you have wrong filename "react-native-config.js" instead of "react-native.config.js"